Author affiliation information for each author for IEEE journal
I am trying to include the affiliation information for all authors, but I am not satisfied with my result.
\documentclass[journal,twoside,web]{ieeecolor}

\title{Advancing Piezoelectric Wind Energy Solutions: Evaluating Turbine Rotor Blade Designs for Sustainable Smart City Infrastructure}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author One \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
                      Author Two \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, 
                      and Author Three \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Department of Mechanical Engineering, University of HHH, City zip code, country\\
                      Email: sss1@email.edu, sss2@email.edu, sss3@email.edu}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2} Engineering Research Center, University of HHHH, City Zip, Country\\
                      Email: sss1@email.edu (Corresponding author)}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.


It’s missing the \end{document}.
Are these packages necessary for this part of the code?
Where can I find and download the "ieeecolor" class?
"I'm not satisfied with my result." Alright, what outcome are you aiming for?

I genuinely want to help, but you're making things more difficult for me.

Could it be that you forgot to include the conference package option?


Full code
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\title{Advancing Piezoelectric Wind Energy Solutions: Evaluating Turbine Rotor Blade Designs for Sustainable Smart City Infrastructure}

\author{
    \IEEEauthorblockN{Author One \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, %
                      Author Two \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, %
                      and Author Three \IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}Department of Mechanical Engineering, University of HHH, City zip code, country\\
                      Email: \email{sss1@email.edu}, \email{sss2@email.edu}, \email{sss3@email.edu}}
    \IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2} Engineering Research Center, University of HHHH, City Zip, Country\\
                      Email: \email{sss1@email.edu} (Corresponding author)}
}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% load it after all other packages
\NewDocumentCommand{ \email }{ m }{\href{mailto:#1}{\protect\nolinkurl{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

